# Problemas ao passar variável por url em wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Pretendo passar uma variável no url no meu projeto em wordpress.

tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<input type="text" id="CodigoUtente" name="CodigoUtente" placeholder="Digite número do utente" />
<input type="button" onclick="carrega()" value="OK" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="Nome" placeholder="Nome" disabled="disabled" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="DataNasc" placeholder="Data Nascimento" disabled="disabled" />

<script>
var http = false;
http = new XMLHttpRequest();

function carrega(){

   var nome = document.getElementById('CodigoUtente').value;

   var url_="conexao4.php?CodigoUtente="+CodigoUtente;
   http.open("GET",url_,true);
   http.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(http.readyState==4){
         var retorno = JSON.parse(http.responseText);

         document.getElementById('Nome').value = retorno.email;
         document.getElementById('DataNasc').value = retorno.cidade;

      }
   }
   http.send(null);

}
</script>
```

o php esta na página `conexao4`

```
$CodigoUtente = $_GET['CodigoUtente'];

if(isset($CodigoUtente)){

   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   $conn->set_charset('utf8');

   $sql = "SELECT Nome,DataNasc from centrodb.PsicUtentes WHERE CodigoUtente = '$CodigoUtente'";

   $resultados = $conn->query($sql);

   $json = array();

   while ($rowResultados = $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {

      $dados = array(
         'Nome' => $rowResultados['Nome'],
         'DataNasc' => $rowResultados['DataNasc']
      );
      $json = $dados;

   }

   echo json_encode($json);

   mysqli_close($conn);

}
```

Quando executo na página recebo estes dois erros na consola:

> GET
>   http://192.168.0.22/conexao4?CodigoUtente=[object%20HTMLInputElement]
>   404 (Not Found) carrega @ psicologia:362 onclick @ psicologia:337
>   VM373:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at XMLHttpRequest.http.onreadystatechange (psicologia:355)

O problema está nesta linha ao chamar a página `conexao4.php`:

```
var url_="conexao4.php?CodigoUtente="+CodigoUtente;
```

No `wordpress` quando chamo outra página na `url` do `ajax` faço desta forma:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./conexao4",
```

Nesta situação não sei como o fazer, pode ajudar?

**Imagem com o erro:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não seria `var url_="conexao4.php?CodigoUtente="+nome;`?

Comment: @Sam, sim, foi um lapso e já resolvi o erro do not found, fica desta forma `var url_="/index.php/conexao4?CodigoUtente="+nome;`. Agora tenho este erro `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.http.onreadystatechange`

Comment: A página `conexao4.php` provavelmente tem HTML, por isso o erro.

Comment: @Sam, não, vou mostrar numa imagem o erro. Vou atualizar a pergunta

Comment: Exatamente isso. Vc quer parsear um retorno do Ajax em JSON, mas esse retorno é um HTML e não um objeto JSON.

Comment: @Sam não entendi. Mas do lado da `conexao4.php` não tenho html, só tenho mesmo o código php

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88805/discussion-between-sam-and-iniciante).

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});

Você pode colocar tbm as informaçoes dentro do DATA, ja que nesse caso vc ta mandando um post.